# laravel pagination links not clicking

Tags: laravel

Appreciate help on this. The pagination links are not working. The page renders correctly but although the links shows as links, when clicked does not work. My structure is as follows:
If I remove the following references in the class file the pagination works but it is not formatted correctly.

use Livewire\WithPagination;
use WithPagination;

Class File: AdminDashboardDirectoryCategoryComponent.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Admin;

use App\Models\DirectoryCategory;
use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\WithPagination;

class AdminDashboardDirectoryCategoryComponent extends Component
{
    use WithPagination;

    public function render()
    {
        $dcategories = DirectoryCategory::paginate(9);
        return view('livewire.admin.admin-dashboard-directory-category-component',['dcategories'=>$dcategories])->layout('frontend_layout.index2');
    }
}
```

View File: admin-dashboard-directory-category-component.blade.php

```
style>
    nav svg {
    height: 20px;
    }
    nav .hidden {
    display: block !important;
    }
</style>

        <section class="content-central">
            <div class="content_info">
                <div class="paddings-mini">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row portfolioContainer">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <table class="table table-striped tester1">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>#</th>
                                            <th>Image</th>
                                            <th>Group</th>
                                            <th>Title</th>
                                            <th>Slug</th>
                                          
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        @foreach($dcategories as $dcategory)
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>{{$dcategory->id}}</td>
                                                <td><img src="{{asset('frontend/assets/images/dir_categories')}}/{{$dcategory->category_image}}" width="60" /></td>
                                                <td>{{$dcategory->category_group}}</td>
                                                <td>{{$dcategory->category_title}}</td>
                                                <td>{{$dcategory->category_slug}}</td>
                                          
                                            </tr>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>

                                {{$dcategories->links()}}
                            
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you add the source code of the rendered page?

Comment: Hi Andrew, I am a laravel beginner. So I am not sure what you mean. I have added the view file which I thought is the source code of the rendered page

Comment: The view file contains the source of that specific view. The view is used when rendering the entire page. When you send with the view some data like `$dcategories` which contains pagination data, the rendered result is what will come out of this. If you right click this wikipedia page and press "view-source" you will se the rendered source code of this page. So if you do the same on your page (right click view-source) and add it here, we get more data to work with.

Comment: Thanks Andrew.. I understand now. The problem however that I cannot paste here as the file exceeds the number of allowable characters.

Comment: www.pastebin.com / www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: https://pastebin.com/p0CPhWYM

Answer (score 0):

https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/pagination

> When using either method, instead of anchor tags in your pagination
> component, you should use wire:click handlers with the following
> methods:
>
> nextPage to navigate to the next page
>
> previousPage to navigate to the previous page
>
> gotoPage($page) to navigate to a specific page.

You are missing these methods.

Comment: Thanks Andrew.. I will have a look

Answer (score 0):

1. You can add Using The Bootstrap Pagination Theme.

   protected $paginationTheme = 'bootstrap';
2. Call all databases.

   $dcategories = DirectoryCategory::all()->paginate(9);